# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de declarar constantes como array?

Tags: php, constantes

Achei muito maneira essa nova *feature* do PHP 5.6.

Agora é possível definir um `array` para o valor de uma constante.

Veja que bacana:

```
const BR_DATES = [
    1 => 'Janeiro',
    2 => 'Fevereiro',
    3 => 'Março',
    4 => 'Abril'
];


print_r(BR_DATES); // Array ( [1] => Janeiro [2] => Fevereiro [3] => Março [4] => Abril )


echo BR_DATES[date('n')]; // Março
```

Vejo que essa implementação diminui a poluição no escopo global em relação a definição de inúmeras constantes. Além disso, se torna bem útil na reutilização de valores que poderiam ser usado de maneira fixa, como no caso acima.

Além das vantagens destacadas, quais são outras vantagens que essa nova implementação trará?

Essa implementação da constante aceitar um array seria a mesma coisa do [Tuple do Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)?

Essa implementação traz algum malefício em relação as versões anteriores?

Comment: @gmsantos, muito obrigado pela correção. Eu só não concordei muito com a parte do `5.6.6` virar `5.6`. Pois eu tinha o php `5.6.0`, e esse recurso NÃO estava implementado. Só não sei se isso se deve por conta da fase ALPHA e não da estável

Comment: Estou indo com base no [changelog](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration56.new-features.php). Mudanças assim não aparecem entre versões de patch, elas são somente para bugfixes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verdade desde da versão 5.6 do PHP é possível constantes como array.

Do meu ponto de vista e pela experiência que tenho diria que é mais uma característica útil que vem de acordo com o aproximar do PHP a alguma da realidade já presente em outras linguagens de programação.

A partir desta versão 5.6 também já é possível:

```
const SEC_PER_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24;
```

Portanto, sim uma novidade mas apenas isso. No entanto e quanto à pergunta...

> Essa implementação traz algum malefício em relação as versões
>   anteriores?

Pode ser problemático em certos ambientes em que não controlamos a versão onde os nossos aplicativos PHP vão ser executados, pois de facto uma constante como array será inaceitável em versões anteriores. Para o efeito existe outra forma...

```
define('MESES', serialize(array('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro' ...)));
```

Desta forma será sempre compatível com versões anteriores do PHP.

Trata-se de uma solução recente e como todos nós sabemos para determinados ambientes de produção não convém passar logo a grandes modificações. Portanto manda a prudência e a experiência em especial que seja utilizado e no imediato em estudo de futuras implementações, mas para produção com algum...muito... cuidado. Hoje e através de um painel administrativo é tão fácil trocar-mos a versão do PHP.

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1

Answer (score 0):

É quase sempre bom ter mais opções, isso torna a linguagem mais versátil. Se a classe tivesse constantes para meses, talvez fosse melhor usar algo como a implementação de exemplo do SplEnum, ou seja, uma constante para cada mês.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.splenum.php

```
<?php
class Month extends SplEnum {
    const __default = self::January;

    const January = 1;
    const February = 2;
    const March = 3;
    const April = 4;
    const May = 5;
    const June = 6;
    const July = 7;
    const August = 8;
    const September = 9;
    const October = 10;
    const November = 11;
    const December = 12;
}

echo new Month(Month::June) . PHP_EOL;

try {
    new Month(13);
} catch (UnexpectedValueException $uve) {
    echo $uve->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Pois se você for comparar se um mês que você recebeu é Janeiro, você usa uma constante e não uma string propensa a erros de digitação.

Sobre as tuplas do Python, pelo que li são semelhantes as listas do Scala, elas são imutáveis, qualquer modificação que você queira fazer na tupla gera uma nova tupla, além de outras características da implementação de uma lista.

No PHP é só uma constante com valor de array.